# How can I redirect hardcoded calls to open to custom files?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I've written some python code that needs to read a config file at /etc/myapp/config.conf . I want to write a unit test for what happens if that file isn't there, or contains bad values, the usual stuff. Lets say it looks like this...

```
""" myapp.py
"""
def readconf()
    """ Returns string of values read from file
    """

    s = ''
    with open('/etc/myapp/config.conf', 'r') as f:
        s = f.read()
    return s
```

And then I have other code that parses `s` for its values.

Can I, through some magic Python functionality, make any calls that `readconf` makes to `open` redirect to custom locations that I set as part of my test environment?

Comment: Look into `unittest.mock.patch`

Comment: As @L3viathan stated, use `unittest.mock.patch`. It would be good for you to move the `with open() as f f.read():` code to seperate function, like `read_file(path)` and then mock this particular function to raise `FileNotFound` exception when called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mock to patch a module's instance of the 'open' built-in to redirect to a custom function.

```
""" myapp.py
"""
def readconf():
    s = ''
    with open('./config.conf', 'r') as f:
        s = f.read()
    return s


""" test_myapp.py
"""
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import myapp


def my_open(path, mode):
    return open('asdf', mode)

class TestSystem(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('myapp.open', my_open)
    def test_config_not_found(self):
        try:
            result = myapp.readconf()
            assert(False)
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            assert(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You could also do it with a lambda like this, if you wanted to avoid declaring another function.

```
    @mock.patch('myapp.open', lambda path, mode: open('asdf', mode))
    def test_config_not_found(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Example would be:

## main.py

```
def _open_file(path):
  with open(path, 'r') as f:
     return f.read()

def foo():
   return _open_file("/sys/conf")
```

## test.py

```
from unittest.mock import patch 


from main import foo

def test_when_file_not_found():
   with patch('main._open_file') as mopen_file:
      # Setup mock to raise the error u want
      mopen_file.side_effect = FileNotFoundError()

      # Run actual function
      result = foo()

      # Assert if result is expected
      assert result == "Sorry, missing file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the config file, you can externalize it or parameterize it. There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Environment variables: Use a `$CONFIG` environment variable that contains the location of the config file. You can run the test with an environment variable that can be set using `os.environ['CONFIG']`.
2. CLI params: Initialize the module with commandline params. For tests, you can set `sys.argv` and let the config property be set by that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to mock just calls to `open` in your function, while not replacing the call with a helper function, as in Nf4r's answer, you can use a custom patch context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from types import CodeType


@contextmanager
def patch_call(func, call, replacement):
    fn_code = func.__code__
    try:
        func.__code__ = CodeType(
            fn_code.co_argcount,
            fn_code.co_kwonlyargcount,
            fn_code.co_nlocals,
            fn_code.co_stacksize,
            fn_code.co_flags,
            fn_code.co_code,
            fn_code.co_consts,
            tuple(
                replacement if call == name else name
                for name in fn_code.co_names
            ),
            fn_code.co_varnames,
            fn_code.co_filename,
            fn_code.co_name,
            fn_code.co_firstlineno,
            fn_code.co_lnotab,
            fn_code.co_freevars,
            fn_code.co_cellvars,
        )
        yield
    finally:
        func.__code__ = fn_code
```

Now you can patch your function:

```
def patched_open(*args):
    raise FileNotFoundError

with patch_call(readconf, "open", "patched_open"):
    ...
```